# Concrete evidence vs. obvious evidence

Tags: adjectives

Which of these two words -- *concrete* and *obvious* -- can we use in this sentence, or are they both possible?

> "The Moon's surface shows _________ evidence of having been affected by impact cratering, which occurs when asteroids and comets collide with the lunar surface."

I want to learn if there is a difference between "concrete evidence" and "obvious evidence". Are they interchangeable in all situations or is there any difference in meaning or contextual usage?

Comment: Any number of words are possible. I could also drop in *questionable* or *irrefutable* (despite them having opposite meanings). Both *concrete* and *obvious* work—but it's not clear what your specific question is.

Comment: Enver, I'm going to suggest that you take some time to read through the [Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners), along with our [_Details, please_ meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). They will help you understand how to better format questions as well as what sort of details and research we'd like to see included in questions posed to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both would work in the sentence but the meaning is a little different.

Concrete evidence:

> Evidence that has been backed up by clear and trustworthy research.

Obvious evidence:

> Evidence that is clearly true but not necessarily backed up by
>   trustworthy research.